# How to properly config IPFS' DNS Link?

Tags: ipfs

I have the subdomain aragon.plasmmer.com, but even with IPFS Desktop+Companion enabled, it isn't redirecting to IPFS.

[image]

plasmmer.com also had an TXT record and isn't redirecting.

How to config it properly?

Comment: You also need to replace the `A` record with an `A`/`AAAA`/`CNAME` pointing to your IPFS node. Also, the TXT record doesn't exist when I query it: perhaps there is some DNS caching issue?

Comment: I've also asked here: https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/how-to-properly-config-ipfs-dns-link/12029/2. Replace the 'A' record? I don't have this. And how to add an 'A'/'AAAA'/'CNAME' pointing to an IPFS node? @Smitop

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: it was an issue with my host's company.

They fixed and the DNS is now properly propagated; so, the TXT records I put were correct.

So this is an invalid question.